# Unable to query with Content Document Link. though ContentDocument is returning results

Tags: file, triggers, salesforce, attachment, apex

[unable to fetch contentDocumentLink LinkedentityId information, even though ContentDocument is fetching information with ContentDocumentId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj7hb.png)

Comment: Do you have any debug logs to share with us? It would be much easier to help you. Also, is there any error? If no, make sure, that you have linked the document to any records, looks like it is just a file with no related ContentDocumentLinks.

Comment: Also it is necessary to add, that if you are using it in Trigger.NEW, means you're doing insert or update or undelete. Note that in insert trigger contentdocumentlink is not yet created.